# How do I organize these "Pearls of Wisdom"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, organization

I consider the answers that I receive to questions on StackOveflow as "Pearls of Wisdom".
I'am afraid that these shouldn't get lost in the mountain of questions that I keep asking day in and out.
I was wondering if there was a way I could organize these precious "Pearls" , yes at the moment there are tags present but they are still generic...
Could you'll propose alternative ways of organizing these "Pears of Wisdom"...

Comment: A nice homebaked pie perhaps?

Comment: I prefer apples to pears, myself ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bookmark the questions/answers using a service like [Delicious](http://delicious.com/) and you can tag them as you see fit.  Using the Delicious Firefox plug-in you can find then quickly via the tags.

Comment: With the tags and boomarks be public or can they be more restrictive?

Comment: You can mark the entry as "private" when you create the bookmark.  You will still have the option of adding tags other have used for the same URL as well as adding your own.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use the favorite mechanism, but we really need a way to organize our Favorites well.

Comment: Private tags in Favorites (like Gmail's Labels) would be nice.

Comment: @Greg: Why don't you put in a feature request for the same :)

Answer (score 5):

Start a blog and then post the answers, with attribution (maybe even with a link back to the actual question as posted on SO), on it.

With each blog post, you start off with the question you had and then post the solutions or answers that helped you out.

You can then tag those blog posts as you wish without clashing with any of those already on SO. You could tag them with pears or peach even, it's on your site, you're the king of the tagging now.

Comment: I do that myself :)

Answer (score 2):

I liked the answer `beggs` gave
(meaning, I would have suggested delicious with tags and groups if it was not already mentioned, +1 there).

There is one more thing I use besides Delicious, for local organization -- [**TiddlyWiki**](http://tiddlywiki.org/wiki/TiddlyWiki).
You can actually export the Delicious bookmarks to an XML and
convert that to a [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) page too (with some scripting).

Answer (score 1):

So bookmark (or 'favourite') them, then just save them locally if you're that obsessed. Alternatively just start an email archive, and email them to yourself.