# Can there be an option to keep your list of bookmarks private?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks

Browsing through meta I see several questions and comments where people ask for their list of bookmarks to be private [{1}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/i-want-to-see-who-marked-my-questions-as-favorites/1109#1109) [{2}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94826/is-seeing-other-peoples-favorites-a-privacy-issue/94838#94838) [{3}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94826/is-seeing-other-peoples-favorites-a-privacy-issue#comment238070_94827) [{4}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work/53580#comment204582_53580) [{5}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75119) [{6}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22953/how-do-i-organize-these-pearls-of-wisdom#comment47377_22956) [{7}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68282/new-feature-to-let-users-select-questions-to-revisit-private-tags). There is a [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94826/is-seeing-other-peoples-favorites-a-privacy-issue) (where I [posted an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138723/189918)) but no explicit feature request, so I thought I would ask: What do you think of an option to keep your list of bookmarks private?

Arguments:

1. People are requesting the feature [{1}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/i-want-to-see-who-marked-my-questions-as-favorites/1109#1109) [{2}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94826/is-seeing-other-peoples-favorites-a-privacy-issue/94838#94838) [{3}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94826/is-seeing-other-peoples-favorites-a-privacy-issue#comment238070_94827) [{4}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work/53580#comment204582_53580) [{5}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75119) [{6}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22953/how-do-i-organize-these-pearls-of-wisdom#comment47377_22956) [{7}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68282/new-feature-to-let-users-select-questions-to-revisit-private-tags). It is my hope that by posting this question we can give people who are interested a central place to cast their votes.
2. Automatically publishing a user's bookmarks is a privacy concern and may discourage some people from contributing to the site. Unlike posting a question or answer, where it is expected that the information will be published and an explicit action is taken to make it public, bookmarks are usually used to bookmark questions for later. Publishing that information is counter-intuitive and done without user consent. See [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138723/189918) for an explanation.
3. If you want to use SE but don't want your bookmarks to be public, you currently have no recourse. Your options are: don't use the site, or don't use the feature. This is not ideal, as SE should encourage all willing contributors, and I do not see a good reason to make the site less functional for some than for others.

My point is: even if bookmarks being public is not an issue for *you* it is obviously an issue for some people. By addressing the issue we can make SE a more welcoming site for everyone and encourage its use, rather than discouraging people and losing valuable contributions.

Comment: *"leaving this problem unsolved hurts Stack Exchange because it discourages some users from contributing"* And this is a significant group? i.e. not just you? Any evidence to back this up?

Comment: 1. Consider browser bookmarks. 2. The Privacy Policy has a specific definition for "personal information" that does not cover a list of favorite questions. 3. To add on to Bart's comment, one can post questions and answers without using the favorites feature. Someone who is concerned about the public/private status of their favorites can elect not to use it with minimal impact on their usage of the rest of the site.

Comment: This isn't a porn site. What do you have to be embarrassed about or hide?

Comment: I don't see the reason why this favourites list is public too. It doesn't bother me but I don't see the need for it. Do people actually bother reading others' favourites?

Comment: I personally don't care but apparently some people do - so reverse the question: Why are favorites public? Who decided that they are and why?

Comment: @skinnyTOD to answer that question, the answer is that "as much as possible, everything done on the Stack Exchange network is as publicly accessible as is possible and where such information would not create a conflict of interest, and does not violate privacy policies." Which I doubt is written down as such, but that's pretty much it. Revealing voting history or flagging history would create conflicts of interest. But mods need to know how a person flagged, so moderators can see flag history. And we are given tools to see if you've voted one person entirely too often.

Comment: Otherwise, there are very few things which are private, and those are not entirely private, because obviously the dev team can see the things that exist in the database. The Stack Exchange staff wants everything to be as public as possible, and favorites have shown no reason to be private, yet. The burden of proof, as they say, is still on the asker here.

Comment: I still feel the burden is on the asker here, as I don't feel like sufficient cause has been shown to suggest that "a known public-facing feature of the site is not made private, but I want to use that feature in a private manner, and expect the site should be changed to reflect that".

Comment: @culix - Well? Do you have any evidence for the assertions buried within the wall of text that is your question? Are you going to even bother responding to any of the comments to your question? None of the Stack Exchange sites are blogs, you know...

Comment: @animuson Thanks for the sanity check. I have gutted my previous version and shortened the question. Better?

Comment: @Bart I have posted several links to requests for this feature as evidence. How's that?

Comment: @waiwai933 Good point about the privacy policy's definition for "personal information". However, it also says they'll explicitly tell you when they're collecting personal information, and favorites don't do that. I believe publishing favorites is a side effect (see my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138723/189918))

Comment: @waiwai933 You could use bookmarks but what about them not existing on every computer you may use, getting lost, etc? Basically, why hobble the features of the SE site for some users?

Comment: @jmort253 >`What do you have to be embarrassed about or hide?` Wanting privacy is not a matter of wanting to hide anything - please see [counterargument 6 of my answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138723/189918). In this case I'm concerned that a decision is being made about what to do with user information without asking their consent nor giving them the opportunity to change it.

Comment: @JackManey Hey, relax, it's only been a few hours. I have a life you know ;) Besides, isn't it supposed to be the [Summer of Love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/) for new users?

Comment: @culix - It's great that you're focused on privacy; it's a wider issue in our world today, and one day our privacy may be completely gone :( But in all seriousness, the solution to this is easy, just use your browser bookmarks. If browsers didn't have bookmarking features, then I'd be one of the first people standing beside you in this fight. But as it is, the developers have more important things to focus on than a luxury such as this. (I call it luxury only because a solution already exists.) Hope this helps! :)

Comment: On the "embarrassed" argument: stack exchange has sites that may have lots of potentially controversial questions (for example, about politics, religion, workplace ethic, etc). Imagine a user who uses their real name and is a well-known employee of a company, for example. They might want to avoid the public association with controversial topics because of the company brand. It's a far-fetched hypothesis, but you get my point.

Comment: Just a short comment: Bookmarks should be private by default. If anything there should be an option to make them public.

Comment: Implemented by *[Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves?noredirect=1&lq=1)*.

Comment: Related: *[Sunsets are often memorable - could we have a tag for deprecated features?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382600)*

Answer (score 38):

**UPDATE 2:** Implemented now as the [**Saves**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves) feature. 
All bookmarks will now be private and migrated automatically to "saves". There's also other improvements with the new feature! My observations below no longer apply.

---

*(outdated)*

For me, **the biggest issue is how unclear it is** that clicking the bookmark icon is an action that is published. Specially considering that in many other sites/apps this isn't the case.

Firstly, you can see the number of people who marked a specific question as bookmark, *but you can't see who they are by clicking or hovering the number* (like you can in github). That's already a huge reason for assuming that the feature is private, without even questioning it.

To add to that, [upvoting/downvoting is anonymous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177662/395508) (thankfully) and the icon is right next to the voting buttons. So, if you know that voting is anonymous, you might easily assume that bookmarks are anonymous too.

The funny thing is that, since voting is something you intentionally do **for the benefit of the community**, I would expect that to be public, but surprisingly it's not! On the other hand, tracking your favorite questions is a thing you do primarily **for yourself**, so isn't it more logical for it to be private?

---

I see three possible solutions for this:

1. Showing a message the first time a bookmark is added, **warning** about the fact that they are publicly visible or **at least change the tooltip** to `Bookmark this question (your list of bookmarks can be seen by others)`.

   - Less than ideal solution, but the **minimum that should be done**.
   - Easy to implement. Simply changing the tooltip can be done without changing anything on the backend or database.
   - Doesn't solve for the people who want to use the feature while keeping their privacy, but at least solves the privacy issue of not being clear that it's public (the biggest issue).
2. (This feature request): Adding a **setting** to show/hide all your bookmarks (maybe on a site-per-site basis). If showing is the default, adding the first bookmark should still display the warning (1), with the link to the setting. Default private is better, though.

   - Reasonable solution. Probably not too difficult to implement.
   - Solves for most people, except the ones that *want to show* their bookmarks for some questions, but *want to hide* for other questions. Probably a negligible minority.
3. Having a **separate button** to keep track of favorite questions privately, while keeping the public "like" feature.

**UPDATE 1:** (3) is kind of implemented in the [new "follow" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345148/upcoming-feature-follow-questions), which is private, and can function as a sort of "bookmark". You can see followed posts in your own profile. However:

- **(1) is still required for clarity.** Specially now that "favorites" has been renamed to "bookmarks" (heavily implies private). Or, do (2) and make private the default setting.
- No search feature yet, as far as I know. Public bookmarks can be searched with `inbookmarks:mine`.
- You can't follow your own posts. So you can't bookmark a favorite answer you posted, or privately bookmark your own question.
- Solved for people who don't mind receiving notifications on these "private bookmarks".

Comment: And no, browser bookmarks dont solve the problem. They are too cumbersome to organize, and are not tied to the sites and your user account. You might want access the sites on multiple browsers/devices and shouldn't be forced to have them synced for this sort of thing.

Comment: Via [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/976488?postid=140778) you can know who favorited a question.

Comment: Oh, OK, you can make your own queries like that? Anyways, what I meant is that you can't see them *by clicking/hovering the number*, like, in an easy and intuitive way. If at least they had this feature, it would be a little less unclear that it's public.

Comment: Yeah, you can write queries like that, assuming the data is made available (deleted posts content is for example not public). I understand you want to have that feature in the UI available for everyone. As it is unlikely this gets added soon, at least not within 6 to 8 weeks, things like SEDE or the stack api and userscripts might be beneficial during the time the feature is not yet implemented, if that even happens.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea stars were public until now.

Comment: See? And the user above has been a member for over 4 years! When people have to go to meta to find out about this sort of thing, then you have a huge privacy issue...

Answer (score 7):

On ca. 2022-10-05, bookmarks became private (and renamed "Saves"). [Announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/178179):

> When we launch, all of the saved posts, custom lists, and private notes you create will be private moving forward. The existing Bookmarks tab on your network profile page will also be rebranded to Saves and made private.

Answer (score 6):

I've updated this to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) since the [Follow feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network) was recently shipped and we have no plans at the moment to revisit this. Currently, Bookmarked content is public but Followed content is private.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. Is there a place I can submit a request to have Bookmarks made private?

Comment: I see on the announcement it says:
`Users (with the exception of moderators and authorized staff) will not be able to see [the follows profile tab] about other users`

This is great! Thanks for taking user privacy into account.
It would be great if both features could be made private. That would make them behave consistently too.

Comment: There's a HUGE difference though. When you follow a post, you get notifications for almost any action that's taken on said post. If you use the "follow feature" as a substitution for the for (private) bookmarks, you start receiving a lot of unwanted notifications as your followed-posts list grows.

Comment: When Saves gets fixed, you could update this to [tag:status-completed]. :-)

Answer (score -3):

I can see what you're saying, and I agree with the people that suggest browser bookmarks (I use them more than favorites). I just have one more thing to add: I have never found any need to look at someone's favorites. There's nothing to help me there. I can only assume others feel the same about them. Therefore, I wouldn't say that there's anything broken with them. Why fix something that isn't broken?

Comment: Would you want a potential employer looking at your favorites and drawing conclusions about you?