# Upvotes with no user

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, up-votes

I was just [querying the stack exchange database](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/109872/votes-with-null-userid), and I noticed that there are records in Votes
for upvotes with null UserId.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Votes
WHERE VoteTypeId = 2
  AND UserId IS NULL


-------- 
28433695 

(1 row(s) affected)
```

What functionality allows this to happen?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Votes on the Stack Exchange network are anonymous. The Data Explorer doesn't allow you to bypass that.

The user IDs are nulled on purpose for the public data dumps because otherwise it would be a serious breach of privacy. You'll notice that there isn't a single upvote with an attached UserId. Same for downvotes.

In fact that's the case with most of them. The only votes that are not anonymized are "Favorite" and "BountyStart" votes (types 5 and 8).

Comment: It's good to know that votes are anonymous, now that I found out that favorites are not.

Answer (score 1):

A [small edit](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/114033/votes-with-non-null-userid) of your query makes it clear:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Votes
WHERE VoteTypeId = 2
  AND UserId IS NOT NULL

- 
0 
  
(1 row(s) affected)
```

<sub>This is really just a comment.</sub>

Comment: Just a comment?!? *gasp* KILL IT WITH FIRE!